# Hardy-Weinberg Equilibrium and two brothers (random mating)

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been working a little with M. G. Bulmer's Principles of Statistics (Dover, 1979) and cannot see how to properly compute half of one question. This should be a basic probability computation, but I am not getting the same answer as the book's suggestion.

Here is the question (Chapter 2, Problem 2.4): If the three genotypes (i.e., $AA$, $Aa$, $aa$) are all distinguishable, find the probabilities that a) a pair of brothers and b) a pair of unrelated individuals will appear the same when $p=q=.5$.

The book offers $.59$ for a) and $.38$ for b). I can get b correctly, but I don't understand how to properly compute part a).

Here's how I am doing it. Consider the 6 possible parental pairs.

1.AA x AA [100% AA] = 0.25x0.25x1
2.aa x aa [100% aa]= 0.25x0.25x1
3.AA x aa [100% Aa]= 0.5x0.5x1
4.Aa x Aa [25% AA, 50% Aa, 25% aa]= 2(0.25x0.25x.25)+.5(.5x.5)
5.Aa x AA [50% AA, 50% Aa]= (.25x.25x.5)+(.5x.5x.5)
6.Aa x aa [50% Aa, 50% aa]= (.25x.25x.5)+(.5x.5x.5)

Total probability = 2(.0625)+.25+2(.015625)+.125+2(.15625)=.5625

This does not seem like a complicated exercise! Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help us help you if you [edit]ed the question to add your computations for part (a).

Answer (score 0):

Your way of thinking is correct.  But there is a simple way to consider the possible parental pairs:
(a). Homozygot; 
(b). Homozygot x Heterozygot;
(c). Heterozygot.

For (a), occurrence probability is 1/4 (1/4*1/4*4), (b) is 1/2, and (c) is 1/4.  In case (a), the next generation will always has the same genotype, so the probability that a pair of brothers will appear the same is p(a)=1. In case (b), p(b)= 1/2.  In the last case, however, the kid could be homozygous (occurrence 1/2) or heterozygous (occurrence 1/2). If the kid is homozygous, the probability of his brother has the same genotype is 1/4 (two kinds of homozygotes).  If the kid is heterozygous, the probability will be 1/2.

The total probability will be: probability of parent's genotype * probability of their kids has the same genotype:

1/4*1 + 1/2* 1/2 + 1/4*(1/2*1/4 + 1/2*1/2) = 1/4 + 1/4 + 3/32 = 0.59375

which matches the answer 0.59 provided by the book.